# How to create a mongodb user for the first time in a Nodejs Application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication

I am using MongoDB with mongoose in the local system in which the mongodbURL did not have username and password. Therefore the database used to get created at the first time when I ran it using the syntax

```
 mongodb://localhost:27012/database
```

But now I want to use a username and password for the database, therefore, I used the given syntax

```
   mongodb://username:password@localhost:27012/database
```

But I now the user does not get created automatically and the script gives me an authentication failure error

How should I create the user the first time?

Answer (score 3):

First, connect to your database using the mongo shell without authentication. Run the following command to create a user.

```
db.createUser({
    user: "username",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [
        { role: "readWrite", db: "database_name"}
    ]
})
```

You probably also want to create an admin so you can create more users later when authentication is enabled.

```
db.createUser({
    user: "username",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [
        "dbAdminAnyDatabase"
    ]
})
```

These users will be created in a database called "admin".

See all of the MongoDB built-in roles here:  https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/built-in-roles/

Edit you mongod configuration. If you are using YAML, add the following lines:

```
security:
  authorization: 'enabled'
```

Here are the mongod config options: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/

If you are using the old format for config set auth to true

```
auth=true
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/reference/configuration-options/

Restart mongod and load your config

```
mongod --config ./mongodb.conf
```

Now you should be able to connect with mongodb://username:password@localhost:27012/database

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect to your database and enable authentication.

To do this, you need to create a user and set some permissions.

You can refer to this documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/enable-authentication/

Hope it helps :)